# Rails 3/Ruby 1.9.2 Date.tomorrow not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rail 3 on Mac Snow leopard

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > Date.today
 => Sun, 25 Sep 2011 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > Date.tomorrow
 => Tue, 27 Sep 2011
```

Is there maybe something wrong with the ruby date class or is this something to do with the way i installed ruby?

Edit:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :039 > Date.current
 => Mon, 26 Sep 2011 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :040 > DateTime.now
 => Sun, 25 Sep 2011 20:47:01 -0500
```

Ok so the rails Date class seems a little buggy. The DateTime class appears to work fine though. Thanks derp and Adam

Comment: I wanted to try this myself but I don't have the `tomorrow` method meaning that one is from rails, in your case probably `today` comes from ruby but `tomorrow` from rails and there may be a discrepancy on what timezone is considered for each one. Try `Date.current` and see if that works against `Date.tomorrow`

Comment: thats what the problem is. Date.current returns Mon, 26 Sep 2011. That solves one problem but raises another.

Comment: Date.tomorrow - always a day away

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am also observing this. You can try `DateTime.now.tomorrow.to_date`.

Comment: You can do 
`Date.today.tomorrow`
or
`Date.today.yestarday`

Comment: Date.current uses timezone like Date.tomorrow does where as Date.today does not.  This unfortunately means that Date.today can equal Date.tomorrow or Date.yesterday depending on timezone.

Answer (score 11):

Was looking info online and came across this:
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6410-dateyesterday-datetoday

---

Check the last comment:

> I do agree with you that its a bit confusing that you need to use
>   Date.current with Date.yesterday instead of Date.today, but the
>   general rule of thumb is Rails does not change how Ruby methods work,
>   which Date.today is. All we can do is add better documentation and
>   make sure people are aware of the subtle difference.

---

In other words, use `current`(rails) instead of `today`(ruby) to avoid problems.

Comment: I'm in BST on London time zone (using Ruby 2.0.0). Today at 16-04-2014 between 0000 and 0059, `Date.current` returns "2014-04-15" whilst `Date.today` returns "2014-04-16". Very confusing, and means my unit tests for "Has this object expired" fail for 1 hour a day!
It's horrible, unexpected, weird behaviour :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `Date.today + 1.day`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using newer version of ruby then you can use `Date.current.tomorrow` to print tomorrow's date.

For example : `puts "Tomorrow's date is : #{Date.current.tomorrow}"`

To know more about data and time please follow below links.

[RubyOnRails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Date.html#method-c-tomorrow) and [RailsGithub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9abe72c7600132aa964ca48c312ef981007ab8b1/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L41)